# Parameterization same variable in all APIs in K6

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, load-testing, k6

I am extracting json value from json response and storing it into array and returning same array but value is getting undefind. Where as in setup function I am able to print value.

```
export function setup() {
    let code = [];
    code = object.func_name();
    code.push();
    console.log('code:::' + code);     // code::: 92409391-4d82-8028-5yy
    return code;
}

export function abc(code) {
    console.log('code: ' + code);  
}

export default function(code) {
    console.log('code1: ' + code);  
}
```

getting **TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined** this error.
But when I changed push functionality -

```
if (!Array.isArray(authcode)) {
  authcode = [];
}
authcode.push();
```

I'm getting value **undefined** in abc and default functions for code.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the array `let code = []` with whatever `object.func_name()` returns, probably some object, when you should return simple data from `setup()`.

Keep in mind that each VU in k6 is a different JavaScript runtime, and `setup()` is executed in its own separate runtime as well, so you can return an object with methods and such, only plain data. The data returned from `setup()` is essentially serialized to JSON and then unserialized in each VU.

Comment: okay then how can I pass the extracted value in all functions ? Also object.func_name() executed once throughtout the scripte so declared it in setup()

Comment: No idea what `object.func_name()` does, but if it just returns something like a string, can't you just `return String(object.func_name())` or something like that. Just return it as simple data that can be converted to JSON.

Comment: Actually whatever I'm returning from setup() which I can't be use in default or any other function.I think the scope of setup() withing itself. B'cz same thing I tried in other or default function then I can able to pass those global or enviroment variables throughout the project or screens. but not able to use enviroment or global variables of setup() in any other function.